# SQL - Derived tables issue

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT VehicleRegistrations.ID, VehicleRegistrations.VehicleReg,  
       VehicleRegistrations.Phone, VehicleType.VehicleTypeDescription, 
       dt.ID AS 'CostID', dt.IVehHire, dt.FixedCostPerYear, dt.VehicleParts, 
       dt.MaintenancePerMile, dt.DateEffective
FROM VehicleRegistrations 
INNER JOIN VehicleType ON VehicleRegistrations.VehicleType = VehicleType.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TOP (1) ID, VehicleRegID, DateEffective, IVehHire, 
                    FixedCostPerYear, VehicleParts, MaintenancePerMile
                  FROM  VehicleFixedCosts
                  WHERE (DateEffective <= GETDATE())
                  ORDER BY DateEffective DESC) AS dt 
ON dt.VehicleRegID = VehicleRegistrations.ID
```

What I basically want to do is always select the top 1 record from the 'VehicleFixedCosts' table, where the VehicleRegID matches the one in the main query. What is happening here is that it's selecting the top row before the join, so if the vehicle registration of the top row doesn't match the one we're joining to it returns nothing.

Any ideas? I really don't want to have use subselects for each of the columns I need to return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT vr.ID, vr.VehicleReg,  
       vr.Phone, VehicleType.VehicleTypeDescription, 
       dt.ID AS 'CostID', dt.IVehHire, dt.FixedCostPerYear, dt.VehicleParts, 
       dt.MaintenancePerMile, dt.DateEffective
FROM VehicleRegistrations vr
INNER JOIN VehicleType ON vr.VehicleType = VehicleType.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, VehicleRegID, DateEffective, IVehHire, FixedCostPerYear, VehicleParts, MaintenancePerMile
    FROM VehicleFixedCosts vfc
    JOIN (
        select VehicleRegID, max(DateEffective) as DateEffective
        from VehicleFixedCosts
        where DateEffective <= getdate()
        group by VehicleRegID
    ) t ON vfc.VehicleRegID = t.VehicleRegID and vfc.DateEffective = t.DateEffective
) AS dt 
ON dt.VehicleRegID = vr.ID
```

Subquery underneath `dt` might need some grouping but without schema (and maybe sample data) it's hard to say which column should be involved in that.

Comment: I was writing the exact same query :P